# Swapping Two items in an ArrayList at the same index

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any way to swap two strings in an ArrayList at the same index with each other?

Let say that at the first place in the list we have answer and question. But now I want every question and answer to swap place with each other. So if the original list looks like this:

uno
one

dos
two

tres
three

In this case `Mylist.get(0).getQuestion()` would be "uno" and `Mylist.get(0).getAnswer()"`= "one".

After swapping:

one uno

two dos

three tres

Now `Mylist.get(0).getQuestion()` would be "one" and `Mylist.get(0).getAnswer()"`= "uno".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like an issue with how you are initializing the object that is inside the list; this doesn't have anything to do with strings in the list. Without posting more code (especially the code for the object, and the code that shows how you are inserting the object into the list), we can't really tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood arrays and properties.

Comment: If you want to switch two fields in an object, it is nothing to do with the fact that it is in an arraylist.

Comment: You can use Collections.swap(List<?> list, String i, String j);
But you're going to need your own set() method since you're trying to use get().

Comment: Hey! Basically, I'm doing a language quiz game, so I did questions in Spanish and answers in English. But now I want to have questions in English, therefore I want to swap them with a simple method.

Comment: @skyever Whatever the solution will be will have nothing to do with the `ArrayList` and everything to do with the object inside the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Hey @John Schwartz! I want to swap multiple objects in the list at different index, how should I do it?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Hey! Should I change the tags or edit the question? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Please post the code you're using currently.

Comment: I have read your question and the code a couple of times now, but I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide some more details, example data, or something we can use for reproducing and understading your problem.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic Just updated the question. Ask me if you have further confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the list for a minute.

Let's say the object you store in the list is an instance of a class called MyObject.

```
class MyObject {
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    // getters / setters / etc
}
```

You can have a method called `swap` that swaps the question for the answer:

```
class MyObject {
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    // getters / setters / etc

    public void swap() {
        String temp = question; // store the question in a temp variable
        question = answer; // question now has the value of answer
        answer = temp; // answer now has the value of question
    }
}
```

Now back to your list, you could call `Mylist.get(0).swap()` and the question and answer will be swapped for that object.

Comment: Since matts answer came in while I was writing mine, and it's the same, I'll just upvote his, and remove mine.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Could you update your question with the code for the object that contains the question and answer fields?

Comment: Sorry! I want to ask: How should I get the "new" question/answer? `Mylist.get(0).swap().getQuestion()`? I just began programming so it might sound idiotic.

Comment: Oh, once you have called swap, the question and answer are now swapped, so you can just get them in the usual way. So first call `Mylist.get(0).swap()` and then call `Mylist.get(0).getQuestion()`. You can't chain the swap().getQuestion() methods together that won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate response!

Comment: You _could_ actually chain the calls if you changed the method signature into `public MyObject swap()` and added `return this;` at the end of the method.